# How to publish in a think tank?

Tags: publications, political-science

I have written a blog post about an International event that I would like to publish in a think tank (I have three DC/London-based think tanks in mind), but none of them have submission section, and they haven't responded to my emails yet. Any advice? Or experience with think tanks? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aren’t you invited to join a think tank? That may be why they don’t have submission sections...

Comment: I have friends who published opinion pieces for Carnegie and others. I guess it depends on your connections? Maybe? They usually have a blog/opinion section.

Answer (score 6):

Think tanks are not academic endeavors. There is no submission process. There is no peer review. The "editorial board" is not made of researchers. Think tanks are essentially lobbies, but for ideas rather than corporations/industries. They work like any other lobby: they pay a lot of money to recognized researchers/politicians/journalists/cultural figures/... so that they can write the conclusion that is asked of them, in order to lend credit to the idea in question. Sending them an article seems like a pointless exercise. They are not interested in your ideas, they are interested in their ideas, and how you can help promote them.

Comment: Yeah, I do not know how to use a website. Srsly! I asked for help...